# Extrating data within database on the base of the datatime

Tags: python, database, mask

I have one dataset with several columns: id, Unixtime, X, Y, etc....
Unixtime is one sequence of date: 01-01-2010 00:00:00, 02-01-2010 00:00:00...etc up to 31-12-2021 23:59:59.

I would like to get data within specific range, between 01-01-2019 00:00:00 until 31-12-2019 23:59:59.
I tried with this script but I have had some problem, because I am not sure if python take all data.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('name.csv', sep=';')
data.info()
start_time = '01-01-2010 00:00:00'
end_time = '31-12-2019 23:59:59'
mask =(data['Unixtime']>start_time)&(data['Unixtime']<=end_time]
x=data.loc[mask]
```

There is another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f_date = data [(data['Unixtime Date'] < '23-03-21') & (data['Unixtime Date'] > '03-03-21')]
```